# Error "controller name" is not a function in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am working with blade template engine. I want to follow a convention of "One Controller per Page" to easily handle code.
I have one JS file which has few controllers which will be used in all files/pages So i included in my template file which will automatically generated in each page.
Code is as follows

```
angular.module('MyApp',['angularFileUpload'])
.factory('MyFactory', ['$http',function($http) {
    return{
      get: function(callback){
          $http.get('my-url')
          .success(function(data) {
              callback(data);
            });
      }
    };
}])
.controller('GlobalController',['$scope','$http','MyFactory',function($scope,$http,MyFactory){
    SchoolFactory.get(function(data){
       console.log(data);
    });
    // Few Function which will be called in all pages
}]);
```

Now When create a new page using that template that includes above JS, I get error. Here is what I create new js file.

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
.controller('SomeController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    // Few Function which will be called in all pages
}]);
```

Any Page which include this module i get error in console that SomeController is not a function.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is same problem which i faced when i started working with Angular JS. Your code has very little error.

> You can create multiple angular.module in single page but only one can have dependencies.

```
angular.module('MyApp',['angularFileUpload'])

angular.module('MyApp')
```

From your second module remove empty array [].

Answer (score 3):

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('SomeController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    // Few Function which will be called in all pages
}]);
```

Remove the , [] in the module. Any time you pass an array to the module function, it recreates the module. Since you want to add something to an existing module, leave it off.